# How can I find two consecutive lines having the the same pattern?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

My text files looks like that:

```
bla : 1 - etc
blb : a - etc
blc : 2 - etc
bld : 3 - etc
ble : 1 - etc
blf : 1 - etc
blg : a - etc
blh : 1 - etc
bli : a - etc
```

I am searching for the pattern `": 1 -"` in the file. Some consecutive lines have the same pattern and I need these two lines plus the next line.

```
ble : 1 - etc
blf : 1 - etc
blg : a - etc
```

Is it possible to extract this lines with `grep`, `sed` or any other tool?

Comment: it is not clear what you mean here. Please [edit] and make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple task with awk:

```
awk -F ' [:-] ' '
    $2 == prev2 {        # if the 2nd field matches the previous 2nd field,
        print prevline   #   print the previous line
        print            #   print the current line
        getline; print   #   get the next line and print it
    } 
    {prev2 = $2; prevline = $0}  # remember these values for the next iteration
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk` instead of `sed`:

```
awk -F: 'm~$2{print m;print;getline;print}{m=$0}' input.txt
```

`m` is a variable which holds the last line. If it matches the part behind the `:` we print `m` and the current line then get the next line and print that as well. At the end `m=$0` stores the current line in `m`.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is better suited to logic constructs like "if" than sed is.

```
$ awk 'substr($0,4,5)==last{print lastline;print;getline;print;} {last=substr($0,4,5);lastline=$0;}' input.txt
ble : 1 - etc
blf : 1 - etc
blg : a - etc
```

Rather than splitting your line by whitespace-delimited fields, I'm assuming you know what you need, and that `: 1 -` really is what you're looking for.  If your input data doesn't match your example, feel free to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use egrep:

```
egrep -A2 ": 1 -" filename
```

where A2 shows the next two lines after the pattern is found.

output:

```
bla : 1 - etc
blb : a - etc
blc : 2 - etc
--
ble : 1 - etc
blf : 1 - etc
blg : a - etc
blh : 1 - etc
bli : a - etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, awk:

```
awk '/: 1 -/  {++i}
     i>1      {print p}
     !/: 1 -/ {if(i>1)print;i=0}
              {p=$0}
     END      {if(i>1)print p}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1 ~/^bl$|e|f|g/' file
ble : 1 - etc
blf : 1 - etc
blg : a - etc
```

If first column starts with bl and ends with e,f or g print those lines.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '/: 1 -/ {CNT++; x[CNT]=$0; next} CNT==2 {print x[1]; print x[2]; print $0} {CNT=0}' *.*
```